# Can't import any apps to Appium Studio

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

I installed AppiumStudio 21.2.7916 but I can’t import or open any apps.
First time I opened it I didn't have the default programs:

Every time I try to import any apk file, from my phone or from my computer, this is what I get:
failure: apk 'internet permission' is missing
Any ideas?

I've seen in other places that I should add:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml. I don't know where to find this xml file.

I have a MacBook Pro, Monterey, 2019

Thanks